# Onclick function with parent-dependant parameters

Tags: javascript, onclick, wrapper

I've got this object :

```
Tr.Competence = function()  {
    var thisCount = //variableNumber;
    this.name = "comp" + thisCount;
    var newRow = parentTable.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);

    var element1 = document.createElement('input');
    element1.type = "button";
    element1.value = "+";
    element1.onclick = function() {
        makeSpecialisation(thisCount, this.name)
    };

    cell1.appendChild(element1);
}
```

and this function :

```
function makeSpecialisation(parentCount, parentEl)  {
    window[parentEl + "SpecialisationCount"]++;
    var specialisationName = parentEl + "Spe" + window[parentEl + "SpecialisationCount"] ;
    //testing variables with an alert
    alert(
       "parentCount=" + parentCount +
       " & parentEl=" + parentEl + 
       " & specialisationName=" + specialisationName + 
       " comXSpecialisationCount=" + window[parentEl + "SpecialisationCount"]
    );
}
```

If element1.onclick calls makeSpecialisation(thisCount, this.nom) directly (without anonymous function), then the variables are alright, but I can't use it after it's been evaluated (on each new Tr.Competence instance call).
=> See : http://jsfiddle.net/hq8U3/2/

If element1.onclick calls makeSpe[...] with anonymous function wrapper, I can call it whenever I want, but variables are either NaN or undefined (or blank on JSFiddle).
=> See : http://jsfiddle.net/hq8U3/3/

What can I do so that my variables work good & I can call them at onClick event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

Since you have an annon function that changes the scope of `this`, so instead of:

```
element1.onclick = function() {
    makeSpecialisation(thisCount, this.name)
};
```

You would need to do this:

```
var self = this;
element1.onclick = function() {
    makeSpecialisation(thisCount, self.name);
};
```

Second: Again because it's annon function you need to wrap it and invoke it to make it call your other function, so the above becomes this:

```
var self = this;
element1.onclick = (function() {
   makeSpecialisation(thisCount, self.name);
})();
```

Third: I think your actually wanting to do this:

```
element1.setAttribute('onclick', makeSpecialisation(thisCount, this.name));
```

In which case the above 2 things are nice to know but irrelevant.

Finally as an afterthought you should use `console.log()` for debugging instead of `alert()`. If you ever forget to take your debugging out `console.log()` won't annoy your users or break your program like `alert()` will.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hq8U3/5/)

Comment: @PublicMani of course all of that is a guess since I'm not entirely sure what your trying to achieve.

Comment: "because it's annon function" isn't the reason. Whether a function is "anonymous" (i.e. created by a function expression without an optional name) or named has no bearing on the value of *this* within a particular execution context. What "changes the scope of *this*" is how a function is called, not how it's defined or initialised. Note that the "scope" of *this* never changes, it's always resolved in the current execution context. What changes is the value, and that is entirely dependent on how the function is called (or through the use of *bind*).

Comment: @RobG I didn't mean to say that because it was an annon function that this changed, but that because he had a function at all between the instance of `this` he wanted to use. Also, how a function is called does not change the scope of `this`. `this` always resolves to be the scope of the closest parent function, whether its annon or not.

Comment: Your first change is likely what the OP wants (i.e. *self.name*). The next part where the function expression is changed to an IIFE changes the outcome entirely, it means the result of calling *makeSpecialisation* is assigned. The value of *this* is set when entering an execution context, which might be related to a function but not necessarily (e.g. global code).

Comment: @RobG Indeed, the fist change/point is what I wanted to achieve, and it solved the problem ! Thanks for the precisions about the scope.

Comment: @ryan Is there any difference between x.setAttribute('onclick') & x.onclick ? It changed nothing to the execution process.
Btw, thanks for the console.log() advice. I think I'll use it untill code is fully ready.